# How to use technical indicators of TA-Lib with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib, technical-indicator

I am new to python and pandas and mainly learning it to diversify my programming skills as well as of the advantage of python as a general programme language. In this programme I am using it to fetch historical data's from yahoo and do some technical analysis  using functions in talib

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import talib as ta

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/1/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2/20/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
f = web.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start, end)
print 'Closing Prices'
print f['Close'].describe()
print f.Close
print ta.RSI(f.Close,2)
print ta.SMA(f.Close,2)
print ta.SMA(f.Volume,4)
print ta.ATR
print ta.ATR(f.High,f.Low,f.Close,3)
```

the above code works till `print f.Close` but then it shows this error

```
 print ta.RSI(f.Close,2)
TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Series)
```

I have used R and its libraries for technical analysis of stocks and It have an inbuilt library called `Quantmod` which makes technical analysis easier and with fewer codes.

```
library(quantmod)
symbol=getSymbols(AAPL)
SMA=SMA(Cl(Symbol),2)
```

is there any similar libraries available for Python?.

Comment: As far as I remember input to `ta.xxx` should be numpy array, not pandas Series. Try `ta.RSI(f.Close.values,2)`. The same, `.values`  property, applies to the other `talib` indicators

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Its working pretty good

Answer (score 7):

Try with;

```
print ta.RSI(np.array(f.Close))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
ta.RSI(f["Close"].values)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you are trying to call SMA / RSI etc functions with pandas series but if you go through the TALIB documentation it shows that they require a numpy array as parameter.

So you can use this :

```
Close=np.array(f['close'][1:])
Modclose=np.zeroes(len(Close))
For i in range(len(Close)):
       Modclose[i]=float(Close[i])

ta.SMA(Modclose,timestamp)
```

The second parameter in SMA is optional though.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ta.RSI expects array of values to process but it gets dataframe. So, you have to convert dataframe to array. Try this:

> print ta.RSI(f.Close.values, 2)